# Error calling .ProtectKeysWithCertificate(cert) Method in IdentitySer4 Resource Server Implementation

Tags: asp.net, identityserver4, data-protection

```
services.AddDataProtection()
 .SetApplicationName("Report Book Resource Server")
 .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(folderForKeyStore))
.ProtectKeysWithCertificate(cert);
```

The last line ".ProtectKeysWithCertificate(cert);" returns error. However the tutorial [here](https://damienbod.com/2016/03/02/angular2-openid-connect-implicit-flow-with-identityserver4/) doesnt. I cant figure out why the method "ProtectKeysWithCertificate()" is returning. 
I will appreciate it very much if anybody out there could indulge me.

Thanks

Comment: As a follow-up. I use ASP.NET Core 1.1 for an application and the same ideas behind that tutorial. I wasn't able to find the .ProtectKeysWithCertificate() method anymore in Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection Version=1.1.0.0. https://i.stack.imgur.com/9k2Wg.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Looks like ProtectKeysWithCertificate is not available in .NET Core. Here is Damien's discussion on Twitter: https://twitter.com/damien_bod/status/698975038142353408